# Xcode 6 creates storyboard warnings

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a storyboard file with 22 scenes and I recently migrated to using size classes and the new "show"/"present modally" segues for iOS 8.

My problem is that every other time I open the storyboard in interface builder, there are new warnings about misplaced frames that I have to fix. After I fix them and save, they keep coming back.

Have others experienced this issue? Is there a way to fix my storyboard so this stops?

Thanks!

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same issue. Have you had any luck with it so far?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I listened to the compiler and took its suggestions on how to fix it, it seemed to fix the problem and it still behaved according to my layout constraints. The way I fixed them is by tapping on the warning symbol and fixed everyone of them

Comment: I have tried that, but the warnings just keep coming back.